# Hyperoperation Golfing

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

## Introduction

> In mathematics, the hyperoperation sequence is an infinite sequence of arithmetic operations (called hyperoperations) that starts with the unary operation of successor (n = 0), then continues with the binary operations of addition (n = 1), multiplication (n = 2), and exponentiation (n = 3), after which the sequence proceeds with further binary operations extending beyond exponentiation, using right-associativity.

<sub>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation))</sub>

---

## Challenge

Your challenge is code this sequence, given 3 inputs, *n*, *a*, and *b*, code a function such that $${\displaystyle H_{n}(a,b)={\begin{cases}b+1&{\text{if }}n=0\\a&{\text{if }}n=1{\text{ and }}b=0\\0&{\text{if }}n=2{\text{ and }}b=0\\1&{\text{if }}n\geq 3{\text{ and }}b=0\\H_{n-1}(a,H_{n}(a,b-1))&{\text{otherwise}}\end{cases}}}$$
<sub>(Also from Wikipedia.)</sub>

---

## Input

3 positive decimal integers, *n*, *a*, and *b*, taken from STDIN, function or command line arguments, in any order. Make sure to specify this in your answer

---

## Output

The result of applying \$H_{n}(a,b)\$ with the inputs

---

## Example inputs and outputs

Input: `0, 6, 3`
Output: `4`

---

Input: `4 5 2`
Output: `3125`

---

## Restrictions

- Your program/function should take input in base 10
- Don't use any built in function that already provides H(n, a, b)
- Standard loopholes apply

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: @JoKing Does it? I'll have a read

Comment: @Arnauld will do.

Comment: (not really. That one "bans builtins" because it's from '13; plus, cumbersome input/output format)

Comment: @dzaima fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>49</s>  47 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b,n)`.

```javascript
a=>g=(b,n)=>n*b?g(g(b-1,n),n-1):-~[b,a-1,-1][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VchLDkAwEADQvZPMyIyo30JSDiIWrU9DZCqIpauXreV7q7nNORzLfrH4cQqzDkY3ToMlQd1IbFsHDiyrzySssOans2S@YNV30ofBy@m3Kdm8gxkqhJxSxOjfJUJGBWJ4AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                  // main function taking a
  g = (b, n) =>       // g = recursive function taking b and n
    n * b ?           // if neither n nor b is equal to 0:
      g(              //   go recursive:
        g(b - 1, n),  //     b = g(b - 1, n)
        n - 1         //     decrement n
      )               //   end of recursive call
    :                 // else:
      -~[             //   this is a leaf node:
        b,            //     if n = 0, return b + 1
        a - 1,        //     if n = 1, return (a - 1) + 1 = a
        -1            //     if n = 2, return -1 + 1 = 0
      ][n]            //     if n > 2, return -~undefined = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 35 bytes

```apl
{⍺=0:⍵+1⋄⍵=0:⍺⍺⍵1⊃⍨3⌊⍺⋄(⍺-1)∇⍺∇⍵-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@NR24TqR727bA2sHvVu1TZ81N0CpMG8XWC01fBRV/Oj3hXGj3q6QALdLRpAStdQ81FHO4gPIrfqGtb@//@od65CnoJGooKHpkISl6GGIZBhyGWgYQakjblMNEyBtBEA)

Comment: you can save a byte by inverting the second guard: `{⍺=0:⍵+1⋄×⍵:(⍺-1)∇⍺∇⍵-1⋄⍺⍺⍵1⊃⍨3⌊⍺}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 86 bytes

(assumes functions can take a reference to itself as an argument)

```
fn 0,_,b,_->b+1
1,a,0,_->a
2,_,0,_->0
_,_,0,_->1
n,a,b,f->f.(n-1,a,f.(n,a,b-1,f),f)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU09C8IwEN3zK45MCV5CW3S0u5ODqxBSTdpAiSWN4L@PF7HgJhzH@@I9N4dXSGU6Fh@hQYMDGtUPu5a1aLGpxLKO9A9smNlgyyIFBvSq91pEVeMVVJGIl3Qu3svosgkxu9ElOAKNqB4uOYU46vzYHPFVkltme3MmJxtmEsTprKlgFZxLBH6NnD6XEqiZkbc88wqTFj8jWlDyH59k2bMD694)